# Exporting duplicated code from inside a yielding generator function

Tags: python, generator

Observe the following method:

```
def _locate(self, text):
        """
        This method accesses preceding locators if these exist, it then calls an overridable helper method called _relocate
        which receives text with readjusted boundaries and searches inside, the basic implemented behaviour is that of a logical or
        """
        if not self.precedents:
            for sub_segment in self._relocate(text, Segment(0, len(text), 1)):
                if self._multiple:
                    yield sub_segment
                elif self.max_segment.prob > self._prob_threshold:
                    yield self.max_segment
                    return
        else:
            for precedent in self.precedents:
                for segment in precedent.locate(text):
                    for sub_segment in self._relocate(text, segment):
                        if self._multiple:
                            yield sub_segment
                        elif self.max_segment.prob > self._prob_threshold:
                            yield self.max_segment
                            return

        # if we haven't found a good enough segment return the best one we came across while locating
        if not self._multiple:
            yield self.max_segment
```

it has some code which is duplicated twice:

```
for sub_segment in self._relocate(text, segment):
    if self._multiple:
        yield sub_segment
    elif self.max_segment.prob > self._prob_threshold:
        yield self.max_segment
        return
```

I naively thought I could probably define a single helper method and have the code just once so started to implement it, however, this proved next to impossible (because of the fact that the code uses both yields and returns) and caused me much more pain in terms of code length and run-time that it was worth.

Not sure what I'm asking exactly (if anything perhaps I'm asking if anyone has any idea of some general approach to sharing generator code that yields or else sees how this can be done here?), but in any case as the topic of generators go I found this experience quite telling and interesting so I thought I'd share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can remove the code duplication by defining a generator of segments outside the loop

```
def _locate(self, text):
        """
        This method accesses preceding locators if these exist, it then calls an overridable helper method called _relocate
        which receives text with readjusted boundaries and searches inside, the basic implemented behaviour is that of a logical or
        """
        if self.precedents:
            segments = (seg for precedent in self.precedents for seg in precedent.locate(text))
        else:
            segments = (Segment(0, len(text), 1),)

        for segment in segments:
            for sub_segment in self._relocate(text, segment):
                if self._multiple:
                    yield sub_segment
                elif self.max_segment.prob > self._prob_threshold:
                    yield self.max_segment
                    return

        # if we haven't found a good enough segment return the best one we came across while trying
        if not self._multiple:
            yield self.max_segment
```

Comment: nice, use a different way to assault the problem, thanks!